# Crystal enterprise sessionMgr.logon setting connection timeout

Tags: java, crystal-reports

How can I set the connection timeout option manually?

When am trying to connect to the Crystal enterprise server programmatically it will show a connection timeout error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, BusinessObjects/Crytal Enterprise does not provide a direct way of configuring the logon timeout. The only logon timeout setting available on CMC is for Trusted Authentication when it is enabled, and it defaults to 0 (no limit).

My experience with this type of error is related to the port used by the CMS service and the machine's firewall configuration. According to the [BOE XI 3.1 Administrator's Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/xi3-1_bip_admin_en.pdf), the CMS service request port is 6400 by default and most firewalls do not open this port by default.

For more information on the CE platform, I recommend browsing the [BO section of the SAP developer network](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/boe-admin).